# Am not able to execute the update stmt using Multiple Joins..SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: oracle, update

```
UPDATE artikel A
SET    A.art_haccp = (SELECT DISTINCT a.art_haccp
                      FROM   artikel A,
                             warengruppe W,
                             sparte B,
                             spartegr C
                      WHERE  ( ( W.wgr_id = A.wgr_id )
                               AND ( W.spa_id = B.spa_id )
                               AND ( B.sgr_id = C.sgr_id )
                               AND ( B.spa_id = 46 ) )
                             AND ( B.spa_id = 46 ))
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT a.art_haccp
               FROM   artikel A,
                      warengruppe W,
                      sparte B,
                      spartegr C
               WHERE  ( ( W.wgr_id = A.wgr_id )
                        AND ( W.spa_id = B.spa_id )
                        AND ( B.sgr_id = C.sgr_id )
                        AND B.spa_id = 46 )
                      AND ( B.spa_id = 46 ));

COMMIT;
```

Comment: SQL server or Oracle? You'll have to determine...

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Am not getting error... the update is happening for all rows..  B.spa_id = 46 not checking

Comment: It is updating all 4500 records instead of 100 records

Answer (score 1):

## Your code is broken.

Your `EXISTS` sub-query is making no references to the table being updated.  As such: if one row returns from that sub-query, then all rows in the table will be updated.

Start by aliasing the table to be updated to something that is not used by any of your sub-queries.  eg:

```sql
UPDATE artikel U
```

After that, make sure both sub-queries include a reference to `U`.

## Comment on Code

I suggest you rewrite the DML statement as a `MERGE` statement.  You can easily see what rows (and values) will be updated by looking at the `USING` sub-query.  Also, `MERGE` is known to be faster (in almost all cases) than this style of update. (eg 30min vs 30sec. YMMV)